# Is there a bicategorical Yoneda lemma for marked lax transformations?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories, yoneda-lemma

The bicategorical Yoneda lemma (see [[Johnson–Yau, Chapter 8]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055)) states that, given a bicategory $\mathcal{C}$ and a pseudopresheaf $\mathcal{F}\colon\mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}}\to\mathsf{Cats}_{\mathsf{2}}$, we have an equivalence
$$
\mathsf{PseudoNat}(\mathsf{h}_{(-)},\mathcal{F})
\cong
\mathcal{F}
$$
in $\mathsf{PseudoFun}(\mathcal{C},\mathsf{Cats}_{\mathsf{2}})$. If one replaces $\mathsf{PseudoNat}$ by $\mathsf{LaxNat}$, then one doesn't have an equivalence anymore, but rather, for each $A\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$, an adjunction
$$
\mathsf{LaxNat}(\mathsf{h}_{A},\mathcal{F})
\rightleftarrows
\mathcal{F}(A)
$$
(see [[nLab, lax natural transformation]](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax+natural+transformation)).

Now, recall that, given

- A bicategory $\mathcal{C}$;
- A subclass $E$ of the class $\mathrm{Mor}_{1}(\mathcal{C})$ of
  $1$-morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ such that, for each $A\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$, we have $\mathrm{id}_{A}\in E$;
- A pair of parallel lax functors $F,G\colon\mathcal{C}\rightrightarrows\mathcal{D}$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to another bicategory $\mathcal{D}$;

we define an **$E$-lax transformation** (see [Sigma limits in $2$-categories and flat pseudofunctors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09429) and [Bilimits are Bifinal Objects](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16394)) from $F$ to $G$ as a lax transformation $\alpha\colon F\Rightarrow G$ such that, for
each $1$-morphism $f\colon A\to B$ of $\mathcal{C}$ in $E$, the lax
naturality constraint

[image]

of $\alpha$ at $f$ is invertible.

As examples, if $E=\{\mathrm{id}_{A}\}_{A\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{C})}$, then $E$-lax transformations agree with lax transformations, and if $E=\mathrm{Mor}_{\mathsf{1}}(\mathcal{C})$, then $E$-lax transformations agree with pseudonatural ones.

**Question:** What is the smallest marking on $\mathcal{C}$ for which an "$E$-marked lax bicategorical Yoneda lemma" holds? I.e. such that we have an equivalence
$$
\mathsf{LaxNat}^+_E(\mathsf{h}_{(-)},\mathcal{F})
\cong
\mathcal{F}
$$
in $\mathsf{PseudoFun}(\mathcal{C},\mathsf{Cats}_{\mathsf{2}})$?

Comment: Shooting completely from the hip, my first conjecture would be $E=$ all morphisms.  There's no other obvious way to choose an $E$ when $\mathcal{C}$ is completely arbitrary, is there?